# SharePoint Calendar Attendees blank

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

Thanks in advance

I've created a new SharePoint Calendar and given it an incoming email address. Lets call it Calendar@Host.Domain.com

I've used my own Outlook (Exchange) to create a new meeting invite and sent it to John.Smith@Domain.com and Calendar@Host.Domain.com

The incoming email has been processed by by the SharePoint Calendar and it's been added but the Attendees field is blank.

How do I get the SharePoint calendar to show the attendees from an incoming email?
*I've added the Attendees Column to the Event Content Type but it's blank

I can get the calendar to show the "E-Mail To" field and that's populated but the "Attendees" field remains blank.

Cheers
Will

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure that the 'Attendees' column is associated with the 'Event' content type for your calendar list. Its possible that its already a column in the list but not associated with 'Event'. To verify, I recommend these steps:

1. In your list settings, enable the management of content types in Advanced Settings if you haven't already.
2. Once content types are enabled, review the list of columns and verify if 'Attendees' is associated with the 'Event' content type (the default for calendars; screenshot below).
3. If its not, navigate to the list of content types above your column settings, and click into the settings for 'Event'.
4. Below the list of columns for 'Event', click on 'add from existing site or list columns'. On the next screen, 'Attendees' should be on of the options available to add. Once added, click 'OK' to save.
5. Retest sending an invite to see if Attendees populate successfully.

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Management of content types has already been enabled and the Attendees column has already been associated with the Event Content Type.

In the Event Content Type information screen I've checked the list of columns and Attendees is listed but unlike some of the other columns Event isn't listed in the Source field. I can't see this making a difference though as the E-Mail To field is the same but I'm able to get these to show up.

I wonder if I could send the invite to the SharePoint calendar but make the colleague a resource as that would be ok